# Pandas forward fill values N times

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 1 and 0 like the following (see below for full reproducible dataframe):

```
2019-04-12 05:15:00  0
2019-04-12 05:30:00  1
2019-04-12 05:45:00  0
2019-04-12 06:00:00  1
2019-04-12 06:15:00  0
2019-04-12 06:30:00  0
2019-04-12 06:45:00  1
2019-04-12 07:00:00  0
2019-04-12 07:15:00  1
2019-04-13 01:30:00  1
2019-04-13 01:45:00  1
2019-04-13 02:00:00  1
2019-04-13 02:15:00  0
2019-04-13 02:30:00  0
2019-04-13 02:45:00  0
2019-04-13 03:00:00  0
```

I have a method that will forward fill non-zeros by `n_exit = 5` times:

```
n_exit = 5
sig.where(sig.ne(sig.shift()) & (sig == 1)).ffill(limit=n_exit).fillna(0, downcast='int')
```

The above code will give the following:

```
2019-04-12 05:15:00  0.0
2019-04-12 05:30:00  1.0
2019-04-12 05:45:00  1.0
2019-04-12 06:00:00  1.0
2019-04-12 06:15:00  1.0
2019-04-12 06:30:00  1.0
2019-04-12 06:45:00  1.0
2019-04-12 07:00:00  1.0
2019-04-12 07:15:00  1.0
2019-04-13 01:30:00  1.0
2019-04-13 01:45:00  1.0
2019-04-13 02:00:00  1.0
2019-04-13 02:15:00  1.0
2019-04-13 02:30:00  1.0
2019-04-13 02:45:00  0.0
2019-04-13 03:00:00  0.0
```

This isn't what I want. The `1` on `2019-04-12 06:45:00` should be ignored because it is within the `n_exit = 5` of the 1 signal that started on `2019-04-12 05:30:00`

What I want instead:

```
2019-04-12 05:15:00  0
2019-04-12 05:30:00  1
2019-04-12 05:45:00  1
2019-04-12 06:00:00  1
2019-04-12 06:15:00  1
2019-04-12 06:30:00  1
2019-04-12 06:45:00  1
2019-04-12 07:00:00  0
2019-04-12 07:15:00  1
2019-04-13 01:30:00  1
2019-04-13 01:45:00  1
2019-04-13 02:00:00  1
2019-04-13 02:15:00  1
2019-04-13 02:30:00  1
2019-04-13 02:45:00  0
2019-04-13 03:00:00  0
```

A potential way to solve this is to replace the values after `1` fives times with an `np.nan`. From there we can then run my code. But not sure how to do this.

```
from pandas import Timestamp
sig = pd.DataFrame({1L: {Timestamp('2019-04-12 01:30:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-12 01:45:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-12 02:00:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-12 02:15:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-12 02:30:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-12 02:45:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-12 03:00:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-12 03:15:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-12 03:30:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-12 05:15:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-12 05:30:00'): 1L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-12 05:45:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-12 06:00:00'): 1L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-12 06:15:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-12 06:30:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-12 06:45:00'): 1L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-12 07:00:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-12 07:15:00'): 1L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-13 01:30:00'): 1L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-13 01:45:00'): 1L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-13 02:00:00'): 1L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-13 02:15:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-13 02:30:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-13 02:45:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-13 03:00:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-13 03:15:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-13 03:30:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-13 05:15:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-13 05:30:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-13 05:45:00'): 1L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-13 06:00:00'): 1L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-13 06:15:00'): 1L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-13 06:30:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-13 06:45:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-13 07:00:00'): 0L,
  Timestamp('2019-04-13 07:15:00'): 0L}}
)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused because there doesn't appear to be any na values in your example. What exactly are you trying to fill?

Comment: sorry the name of the question is confusing. i am trying to roll forward the value of 1 for 5 times. i guess indirectly you can treat the 0 as nan.

Comment: i mis-understood, ive editted my the potential suggestion i made

Answer (score 1):

I might be burned for that, but when I find something too complex to be easily expressed in pandas, I revert to the good old plain Python way over the underlying numpy arrays.

It may not be as efficient of a truely vectorized operation, but as it only iterates over a numpy arrays, it is still much faster than pandas iterrows. Here I would use:

```
new_col = np.zeros(len(sig)).astype(np.int64)
state = 0
for i, val in enumerate(sig.iloc[:, 0].values):
    if state == 0:
        if val == 1:
            state = 5
            new_col[i] = 1
    else:
        new_col[i] = 1
        state -= 1

sig['new_col'] = new_col
```

It gives:

```
                     1  new_col
2019-04-12 01:30:00  0        0
2019-04-12 01:45:00  0        0
2019-04-12 02:00:00  0        0
2019-04-12 02:15:00  0        0
2019-04-12 02:30:00  0        0
2019-04-12 02:45:00  0        0
2019-04-12 03:00:00  0        0
2019-04-12 03:15:00  0        0
2019-04-12 03:30:00  0        0
2019-04-12 05:15:00  0        0
2019-04-12 05:30:00  1        1
2019-04-12 05:45:00  0        1
2019-04-12 06:00:00  1        1
2019-04-12 06:15:00  0        1
2019-04-12 06:30:00  0        1
2019-04-12 06:45:00  1        1
2019-04-12 07:00:00  0        0
2019-04-12 07:15:00  1        1
2019-04-13 01:30:00  1        1
2019-04-13 01:45:00  1        1
2019-04-13 02:00:00  1        1
2019-04-13 02:15:00  0        1
2019-04-13 02:30:00  0        1
2019-04-13 02:45:00  0        0
2019-04-13 03:00:00  0        0
2019-04-13 03:15:00  0        0
2019-04-13 03:30:00  0        0
2019-04-13 05:15:00  0        0
2019-04-13 05:30:00  0        0
2019-04-13 05:45:00  1        1
2019-04-13 06:00:00  1        1
2019-04-13 06:15:00  1        1
2019-04-13 06:30:00  0        1
2019-04-13 06:45:00  0        1
2019-04-13 07:00:00  0        1
2019-04-13 07:15:00  0        0
```

correctly ignoring the 1 at `2019-04-12 06:45:00`

Comment: yea thats the way i am doing it now but I have like millions of rows....lol

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your code is that `0` is not the same as `NaN`. It's tough to test an answer because your code to populate a dataframe does not work and I didn't bother troubleshooting it.

Basically, you are used three separate pieces of erroneous code to try to do the same thing. The solution I wrote below should work in the way you described in the question. I had to make some assumptions based on your code `sig['ne']` is the column with 1s and 0s.

```
 # First remove 0 values
 from numpy import nan
 mask = (sig == 0)
 sig.loc[mask] = nan

 # Then ffill as you originally intended.
 sig = sig.fillna(method='ffill',limit=5)

 # Finally, add back the other 0s
 sig = sig.fillna(0)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you missed the point that the row at `2019-04-12 07:00:00` had to keep its 0.